# How to ignore URL at the end of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, url, mod-rewrite

I have a URL

```
original: https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/
```

Sometimes users or web crawlers write the URL differently:

```
https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/65485/

https://www.example.com/video/12345/

https://www.example.com/12345/
```

I want all 3 URLs to redirect (forward) to the original:

```
https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/
```

My current htaccess rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/$      view_video.php?id=$1&dir=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/$              view_video.php?id=$1&dir=fake [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##To rewrite URL https://www.example.com/12345/
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ view_video.php?id=$1&dir=fake [NC,L]

##To rewrite URL https://www.example.com/video/12345/
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/?$ view_video.php?id=$1&dir=fake [NC,L]

##To rewrite URL https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/65485/
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/[0-9]+/?$ view_video.php?id=$1&dir=$2 [R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/view_video\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]*)&dir=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) video/%1/%2 [R=301,L]

##To rewrite URL https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/
RewriteRule ^video/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ view_video.php?id=$1&dir=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Mitra, oh ok, let me edit my solution now, do give me 5 mins or so, cheers.

Comment: @Mitra, could you please try now once and let me know if that helps you?

Comment: Should I keep the old one

Comment: @Mitra, In my humble opinion these look better to take care of `/` at last too, let me know in case of any more queries here.

Comment: just one problem this url not redirecting to https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/65485/ = https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/

Comment: @Mitra, 3rd rule set is for url like `https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/65485/` could you please do let me know if you have placed all rules in your .htaccess and you have cleared your browser cache before testing URLs.

Comment: Yes I have cleared and tested all just the last one not redirecting, Please see my original URL except three

Comment: All URLs should go on this URL: `https://www.example.com/video/12345/name-of-the-video/`

Comment: @Mitra, I added 4th rule also now, I think this is what you were looking correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226710/discussion-between-mitra-and-ravindersingh13).